Mac Lane Chapter 7 Section 2 Exercise 1
Let $\mathcal{C}$ be a monodical category, with the monodical product written $\otimes$, the associator denoted $\alpha$, and the left/right unitors denoted $\iota^\ell,\iota^r$ respectively.  Mac Lane chapter 7 section 2 exercise 1 asks us to deduce that two putative coherence axioms

for monoidal categories are already consequences of the pentagon identity and the 'middle exchange' unit coherence law. The 'hint' for the exercise dictates that we write out the pentagon identity with the first two objects replaced with the unit for the monoidal product, then 'fill out the inside' using $\iota^r$ twice, the middle exchange unit law twice, and naturality where appropriate. In trying to do so, this is as far as I've gotten:

The left and right triangles commute by the middle exchange unit law, and the top trapezoid commutes by naturality, so far so good. The bottom of the diagram has me confused; we can add an arrow as below

and the resulting trapezoid commutes by naturality, but the final lower right triangle is the same diagram we're trying to establish commutativity for tensored with the unit on the left, so I don't see how to show that it commutes. Any assistance is appreciated.
Note: The associator MacLane uses moves brackets in the opposite direction of the one above, but since they're isos this should be irrelevant to things working out (modulo appearances, which might be why I'm missing this one).

See here, or here for a formalised proof.

@NaïmFavier Thank you.

And of course, a day after posting the question I realize I'm an idiot; the last diagram in my question is the answer, if we erase the little unnecessary triangle I drew in the center:

Now we just observe that everything except the bottom right triangle commutes by the pentagon identity, two applications of the middle exchange unit law, and naturality, and since this is a diagram composed entirely of isos if all shapes but one inside it commute then that shape also commutes. We then observe that tensoring with the unit on the left is an equivalence by definition since the left/right unitors are isos with the identity functor, so the bottom right triangle commutes with the unit eliminated on the left and we're done. The proof dualizes for the second identity, replacing the last two objects in the pentagon identity with units instead of the first two.
Note: This is essentially the same proof found on the nlab (and originally in Max Kelly's 1964 paper On MacLane’s Conditions for Coherence of Natural Associativities, Commutativities, etc.), as pointed out by Naïm in his comment above.
